# VB.NET Auto-Implemented Properties - Compatibility between VS2010 and VS2008

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010, automatic-properties

I am working on an ASP.NET project where I use VB.NET within Visual Studio 2010. Some of the other developers on the project are using Visual Studio 2008. We all check our code into single SVN repository. I would like to start using Auto-Implemented Properties within VB.NET ...

```
Property FirstName as String
```

instead of ...

```
Private FirstName as String
  Public Property FirstName() As String
  Get
    Return _FirstName
  End Get
  Set(ByVal value As String)
    _FirstName = value
  End Set
End Property
```

My concern is that this could mess up things for those using VS2008. What would happen if someone using VS2008 needed to modify my class that made use of Auto-Implemented Properties? I am assuming that since everything compiles down to IL code then there would be no issue in binary compatibility. Though a problem would arise when editing source. I am a correct or mistaken on this? Thank you.

Comment: Automatic properties aren't supported in VB.Net 9.0 (the highest version supported by VS 2008), so this will give an error in VS 2008 on compilation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They will get a compilation error

> Property missing 'End Property'.
>
> Property without a 'ReadOnly' or
>   'WriteOnly' specifier must provide
>   both a 'Get' and a 'Set'.